# How to give my client option to add images, text and way to style both in my custom coded WordPress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I need advice from skilled WordPress Theme creators.
I have created my own custom WordPress theme and would like to make so that my client can log in to WordPress User account and be able to add images, text and have option to style both.
I am a beginner and would be very grateful if i could get detailed explanation, step by step.

Thank you in advance

Tried google search and ChatGPT but so far without solid results.

Answer (score 1):

### Use the plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

---

### Step 1: Create ACF blocks

I would suggest using ACF blocks for Gutenberg, that's our go-to options for couple of reasons:

- Makes your theme modular,
- Easy to use with the default WP page builder,
- Reusability

So what are ACF blocks? In simpler words, look at them like sections from a page. Your "About us" section would be a separate block, "Contact Us" would be another block, "Pricing plans" would be another separate block and so on. Users would be able to create a **new page** or **new post**, and they can add blocks to the page/post. The new blocks will be available just like the default Paragraph, Heading, List and other Wordpress blocks are available.

Good resource to learn more in details:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/blog/acf-5-8-introducing-acf-blocks-for-gutenberg/

By making your theme modular, your clients would be able to add new sections, delete sections, reorganise existing sections and etc.

How to register a block?

```
add_action('acf/init', 'register_new_acf_blocks' );
function register_new_acf_blocks(): void {
    acf_register_block( array(
        'name'              => 'section-title',
        'title'             => __('Section Title'),
        'description'       => __('A section title with optional sub text.'),
        'render_callback'   => 'render_block',
        'category'          => 'formatting',
        'icon'              => 'admin-comments',
        'keywords'          => array( 'title', 'section', 'heading' ),
    ) );
}
```

And then your render callback:

```
function render_block( $block ): void {
    $slug = str_replace('acf/', '', $block['name']);

    ob_get_clean();
    
    require get_theme_file_path("/resources/blocks/content-{$slug}.php");
    
    $content = ob_end_clean();
    
    echo $content;
}
```

So in our theme, we **MUST** have `..path-to-theme/resources/blocks/content-section-title.php`. The `content-section-title.php` file will act as a view for the block, therefore your entire HTML goes here.

---

### Step 2: Add ACF fields in your block

Lets pretend that `content-section-title.php` is a simple section with the following code.

```
<h1> Your title </h1>
<p> Your sub-title for the section </p>
```

This will make your code STATIC (as it is now), since the H1 and P text values are hard coded. In order to make them dynamic, thus allow your users to edit these blocks - follow [this part](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/getting-started-with-acf/) of the ACF documentation.

Let's assume that you create new ACF fields called 'section_title' and 'section_subtitle'. You will need to adjust your template view to look like this:

```
<h1> <?= get_field('section_title') ?> </h1>
<p> <?= get_field('section_subtitle') ?> </p>
```

Now whenever a user create a block and clicks on it from the WP Gutenberg editor, they will see 2 input fields for the Title and the Subtitle in the right sidebar of the editor. The values the users will enter, will be the one displayed on the front-end of the site where this block was used.

Comment: Answer is so detailed,  i love it and i will look into it. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome @Rewoolbebol.

Check my profile for my email, I can help you out  when I have some free time if you are not able to solve this on your own.